# Correct perspective distortion

Tags: python, camera, distort

I've modeled a pool table with some balls on top of it, also putting a camera approximately above its center. I've set the camera type to "Perspective", which gives rise to the distortions that you see below:

[image]

The question is: how can I remove such distortion programmatically? I know I could set the camera type to "Ortographic" to obtain an image without distortions, but that's not what I'm looking for.

More precisely, what I would like to do is map 2D pixel coordinates of the distorted image to 2D pixel coordinates of the corresponding undistorted image. Here, "distorted image" refers to what the camera sees when in "Perspective" mode, whereas "undistorted image" refers to what the camera sees when in "Ortographic" mode. I hope the question is clear enough.

You can assume to know what the exact position of the camera is as well as the diameter of each ball in the table. Also, keep in mind that I would like to do this with a Python script, and not via Blender's graphical user interface.

Comment: Hi. Could you explain *why* setting the camera to Ort**h**ographic is not what you want?

Comment: Because I'm trying to model a real scenario in which I don't have an ortographic camera, but rather a panoramic camera with fisheye. I found that I'm able to undistort an image taken with a panoramic camera and make it look like it was taken with a perspective camera, but now I don't know how to make the second step, namely transforming the image further to make it look like it was taken with an ortographic camera.

Comment: You can't get an image that is equivalent to the scene under orthographic projection from a single 2D image created with perspective projection. You're missing information about the scene (e.g. due to occlusion) as well as depth information.

Comment: @RobertGützkow Yeah, I guess occlusions might be a problem, but aside from that, I do have some information about the scene. Like I said, I know the height of the camera and I know the exact dimensions of the balls and the table, so depth information is there, somehow (unless you meant something different). Are you saying I can't do anything even though I know such information?

Comment: Alright, my statement was an explanation why this doesn't work in general. What you can do is undistort the image based on the calibration of the camera, which may get pretty close to what you would like to have. However, that is still not the same as an orthographic projection. Either way this has (almost) nothing to do with Blender since this is actually a computer vision problem. You would have to determine the intrinsic and extrinsic properties of the camera. Some information about the extrinsics are already known.

Comment: [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html) should allow you to accomplish your goal.